# C# Take a piece of text at a time in a textbox

Tags: c#, email, text, textbox, take

I have a textbox(`textBox2`) where are the email:
`thisemail@gmail.com,hello@yahoo.it,YesOrNo@gmail.com,etc..`

I have a function that sends an email:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var smtpServer = new SmtpClient(textBox5.Text);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
    mail.To.Add(textBox2.Text);
    mail.Subject = textBox6.Text;
    mail.Body = textBox7.Text;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = checkBox1.Checked;
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox9.Text));
    var x = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
    smtpServer.Port = x;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = checkBox2.Checked;
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

I want you send an email to each email separately.
That is, when I press the `button1` to take him an email at a time and send the email until you end up. How can I do?

Comment: What do you mean with "an email to each email separately"? When there are multiple recipients in `textBox2.Text`?

Comment: [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) the string then loop through the items in the array you get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just don't want all the recipients to see the other addresses you could just use the blind carbon copy instead

```
mail.Bcc.Add(textBox2.Text);
```

If you really do want to send the same email multiple times you can just split the addresses on the comma and pass them to the code you already have in a separate method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var address in textBox2.Text.Split(","))
        SendMessage(address);
}

private void SendMessage(string address)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    var smtpServer = new SmtpClient(textBox5.Text);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
    mail.To.Add(address);
    mail.Subject = textBox6.Text;
    mail.Body = textBox7.Text;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = checkBox1.Checked;
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox9.Text));
    var x = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
    smtpServer.Port = x;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = checkBox2.Checked;
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string emailList = "thisemail@gmail.com,hello@yahoo.it,YesOrNo@gmail.com";
string[] emails = emailList.Split(","); // replace this text with your source :)

foreach(string s in emails)
{
var mail = new MailMessage();
            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient(textBox5.Text);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
            mail.To.Add(s);
            mail.Subject = textBox6.Text;
            mail.Body = textBox7.Text;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = checkBox1.Checked;
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox9.Text));
            var x = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            smtpServer.Port = x;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = checkBox2.Checked;
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```